# Multiple Text rows in QGIS divided by lines

Tags: qgis, labeling, mapping, text

My Problem seems rather simple but I had no sucess for over a day now.
Basically I have multiple (polygon) shape files that need text information in them (or if the shape is to small outside of it with a line pointing to where it belongs) and show in the map. Its only for 10 layers so I wouldnt mind doing it manually - if i knew how. For a similiar task I added invisible point layers and labeled them (i know probably should have used labeling tool) but this problem remains tricky since the text information is rather complex.
The text hast to look something like this.
[image]

Sometimes only two rows, sometimes 4, different information in them per layer. I cant find any option to do multiple rows, that are divided by this lines at all.

I dont need a complex solution, If there is a possibilty where I can enter this stuff by hand as text I would be happy. But the format hast to be like this which is my problem.

Comment: Can you provide an example how you create these labels? Are they harcoded within the attribute table? Are they a concatenation of several attributes? Are they conditional?

Comment: Sorry, no time for a proper answer but this tutorial from Klas Karlsson (youtube video) may give you some idea for achieving what you need : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ySYmZv7HQiY&ab_channel=KlasKarlsson

Comment: At the moment they are only on paper in front of me. I have created them by hand since I do field work. I now have them to show up on my 10 different layers that represent different areas in my map and are polygon shapes.
Each label is complelty unique and I have no digital data where they come from. If I could add them manually one by on and have them show as text that would be enough. They dont need to be connected to the layer itself as far as i can move them there manually
Edit: Also each layer gets only one of these as I said they are all unique